# Maybe with a structural pattern matching interface

Tags: python, python-3.x, object-oriented, optional

With a reference implementation for [PEP 622](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0622) now available in a Jupyter [playground](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/gvanrossum/patma/master?urlpath=lab/tree/playground-622.ipynb), I decided to copy over my favourite [feature of Rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/) in full to Python.
**Note**: this won't be released until Python 3.10 but there is a [reference implementation available](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0622/#reference-implementation).

Given that I do a lot of interacting with JSON through the web, having a somewhat safe but hacky solution using `Some` is helpful. And so I've diverged from Rust's Some in that you can get items from the underlying datatype by indexing or through attribute lookup.

This is useful if I just want the first phone number from the user.

```py
match user.phones[0]:
    case Some(phone):
        print(f"No  : {phone}")
    case _:
        print("No phone number provided")
```

To allow for this interface I've built a `Null` class that returns `Null` through indexing or attribute lookup. This is only needed if you're using these additional interfaces, and so `None` can be used otherwise.

`maybe.py`

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from typing import Any, Generic, Type, TypeVar, Union, cast

__all__ = [
    "NSome",
    "Null",
    "Some",
]

T = TypeVar("T")


class _Null(type):
    def __getattr__(self, key: Any) -> Type[Null]:
        return Null

    def __getitem__(self, index: Any) -> Type[Null]:
        return Null

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"Null"


class Null(metaclass=_Null):
    pass


class Some(Generic[T]):
    __slots__ = __match_args__ = ("_value",)
    _value: T

    def __init__(self, value: T) -> None:
        self._value = value

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"Some({self._value})"

    def __getattr__(self, key: Any) -> Union[Type[Null], Some[Any]]:
        try:
            return Some(getattr(self._value, key))
        except AttributeError:
            return Null

    def __getitem__(self, index: Any) -> Union[Type[Null], Some[Any]]:
        try:
            return Some(cast(Any, self._value)[index])
        except IndexError:
            return Null


NSome = Union[None, Type[Null], Some[T]]
```

Usage takes advantage of [PEP 622](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0622) allowing for somewhat long but very customizable usage.

```py
import collections
import math

from maybe import NSome, Null, Some


def divide(numerator: int, denominator: int) -> NSome[float]:
    if denominator == 0:
        return None
    else:
        return Some(numerator / denominator)


def display(value: NSome[float]) -> None:
    match value:
        case Some(x):
            print(f"Result: {x}")
        case _:
            print("Cannot divide by zero")


User = collections.namedtuple("User", "name age phones")


def display_user(user: NSome[User]) -> None:
    match user.name:
        case Some(name):
            print(f"Name: {name}")
        case _:
            print("No name provided")
    match user.age:
        case Some(age):
            print(f"Age : {age}")
        case _:
            print("No age provided")
    match user.phones[0]:
        case Some(phone):
            print(f"No  : {phone}")
        case _:
            print("No phone number provided")


def main() -> None:
    display(divide(2, 3))
    display(divide(2, 0))

    display_user(Some(User("name", 123, ["123456789"])))
    display_user(Some(User("name", 123, [])))
    display_user(Null)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This outputs the following in the [playground](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/gvanrossum/patma/master?urlpath=lab/tree/playground-622.ipynb).

```
Result: 0.6666666666666666
Cannot divide by zero
Name: name
Age : 123
No  : 123456789
Name: name
Age : 123
No phone number provided
No name provided
No age provided
No phone number provided
```